# React Query useInfiniteQuery invalidate individual items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

How can I invalidate a single item when working with useInfiniteQuery?
Here is an example that demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

Let`s say I have a list of members and each member has a follow button. When I press on to follow button, there is a separate call to the server to mark that the given user is following another user. After this, I have to invalidate the entire infinite query to reflect the state of following for a single member. That means I might have a lot of users loaded in infinite query and I need to re-fetch all the items that were already loaded just to reflect the change for one item.

I know I can change the value in queryClient.setQueryData when follow fetch returns success but without following this with invalidation and fetch of a member, I am basically going out of sync with the server and relying on local data.

Any possible ways to address this issue?

Here is a reference UI photo just in case if it will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not currently possible because react-query has no normalized caching and no underlying schema. So one entry in a list (doesn't matter if it's infinite or not) does not correspond to a detail query in any way.

If you prefix the query-keys with the same string, you can utilize the partial query key matching to invalidate in one go:

```
['users', 'all']
['users', 1]
['users', 2]
```

`queryClient.invalidateQueries(['users])` will invalidate all three queries.

But yes, it will refetch the whole list, and if you don't want to manually set with setQueryData, I don't see any other way currently.

If you return the whole detail data for one user from your mutation, I don't see why setting it with setQueryData would get you out-of-sync with the backend though. We are doing this a lot :)

Comment: We have this issue now @TkDodo is there a way to do this today in version 4?

Comment: do what exactly?

Comment: well lets say we have an infitite query and a list that renders rows with items. Each item has a like button but that button calls another api to set a state in a different relational table. let say we have /api/tweet for the paged data and /api/tweet/[id]/toggleLike.
What we are struggeling with is how to optimisticly update that one item in the list..

Comment: oh and this might be poor design in the api. But each tweet returns a calculated value for if you have liked it or not. IE tweet {msg: string, like: bool (appended in api from relational data and cant be updated with a put to /tweet/[id].)}

Comment: have a look at the github discussions: https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/3360 or https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/4252#discussioncomment-3823114