# React query prefetch an InfiniteQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have this simple component that uses the useInfiniteQuery. I want somehow to prefetch only the second page. Docs says to use prefetchInfiniteQuery but for some reason i cannot gei it to work. Any ideas what iam doing wrong in the click listener?

Im using react query v3.

```
function Projects() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const getNowPlaying = (props) => {

    return Axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?page=${
        props.pageParam || 1
      }&api_key=<redacted>`
    );
  };

  const state = useInfiniteQuery("projects", getNowPlaying, {
    getNextPageParam: (props) => {
   
      const { total_pages: totalPages, page } = props.data;

      return page >= 3 ? false : page + 1;
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      {state.data.pages.map((group, i) => (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          {group.projects.map((project) => (
            <p key={project.id}>{project.name}</p>
          ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            state.fetchNextPage();
          }}
          disabled={!state.hasNextPage || state.isFetchingNextPage}
        >
          {state.isFetchingNextPage
            ? "Loading more..."
            : state.hasNextPage
            ? "Load More"
            : "Nothing more to load"}
        </button>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
      
          queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery("projects", () =>
            getNowPlaying({ pageParam: 2 })
          );
        }}
      >
        Prefetch
      </button>
      <div>
        {state.isFetching && !state.isFetchingNextPage ? "Fetching..." : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to do page-level operations using `useInfiniteQuery`. The closest you can do is calling the function and modifying the cache directly.

I made a demo codesandbox here of your issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-infinite-prefetch-45bx1g

In this case, clicking `prefetch` will replace the 1st page because it replaces the `"projects"` key data entirely, instead of just keeping the particular `pageParam` in cache for when its needed.

This is because InfiniteQueries work with an "all-or-nothing" implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853209/4088472

You will need to build the behavior you need with `useQuery` and keys structured as `["project", pageParam]` in order to pre-fetch specific pages.